# Achievements and inbox counters misaligned in mobile web view

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

When I have a reputation notice, it slides off the right of the screen and gives me a horizontal scrollbar.

Using Chrome 64 on Android.

[image]

Comment: Same on iOS, and with the inbox.

Comment: Me too, iPhone SE running Grazing (an alternative browser); was okay yesterday. No scrollbar, just ugly, and looks like maybe there's an achievement behind the +20 (notice the green bars on the icon which looks like a histogram; it's usually white when you have no recent events, and green when something happened there).

Comment: Confirmed on Firefox 57.0.4 on Android 7, exactly as @tripleee described it.

Comment: Same with Chrome 60 on Android 4.3

Comment: Me, too. Chrome 64.0.3282.137 on Android 7.0. The red "Inbox" number is similarly misaligned rightward.

Comment: I've got the misaligned number on desktop as well, but since I don't have a tiny screen I don't get the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas How is it misaligned on desktop? I'm sure we would have far more interaction on meta if that were the case.

Comment: Looks the same as in your screenshot, offset to the right. It's not consistent, though, so it might've just been a gremlin. :)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas That's not possible, the desktop site has a completely different top bar. Are you sure you weren't looking at the mobile site?

Comment: Cross-site duplication [Inbox notification and reputation score is misaligned in mobile web view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306538/312043)

Comment: Is it ***that*** hard to rollback to an older revision of website deployment? Why is this [meta-tag:status-planned]???

Comment: @iBug Probably because they've done a lot of other changes that can't be rolled back. Rolling back is almost always a difficult option.

Comment: @DavidG Even though I have no knowledge in web development, I know it's a (probably) simple tweak in the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: @iBug And that means rolling forward with a fix, not back. :)

Comment: Should be fixed now, can someone confirm?

Comment: @Paweł Go upvote one of my posts and I'll check... ;)

Comment: @Paweł Seriously though, if I just make the element visible and insert `+10` into the span, it looks fine. However, if the rep gain is 100 or more, it falls off the edge still. (tested by getting the 100rep trusted user bonus when I join another site)

Comment: @Paweł Fixed (tested using Microsoft Edge). Thanks!

Comment: @YohDeadfall I assume with less than 100 rep gain?

Comment: Yep, I have only +10, but it looks like always now.

Comment: @YohDeadfall Well I'm pretty sure that previously, with 100+ rep it worked also.

Comment: @Paweł looks like it's not fixed 100% yet, see answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363015/447356) and comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306538/inbox-notification-and-reputation-score-is-misaligned-in-mobile-web-view)

Comment: I will take closer look, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed on 14th February.

<sub><sup>*Adding this answer because Shog9 didn't when he marked this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and it's getting bumped to the homepage due to having no answer</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

I disagree!! This is not [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!! See my report here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306677/350567

> Seems fixed, but only **partially**. It looks fine if you have no more than `+99` rep change, and things are still wrong beyond that.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: I already mentioned this in the [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362829/achievements-and-inbox-counters-misaligned-in-mobile-web-view/363015#comment554984_362829) above.

Comment: Only when they choose the center of the green box as the alignment point (never know any CSS, but I have experience creating Flash games so I know this).

Comment: I'd regard this as a separate issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I disagree. It previously worked fine and has only been semi-fixed. You think there should be another meta post?

Comment: @DavidG: there are two separate issues here; misalignment (which also affected the inbox) and incorrect handling of overflow (only affects the achievements score). I think this one deserves separate attention.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Even though "both" issues were almost certainly created by the same change?

Comment: @DavidG: yes. A change in software can lead to multiple, separately addressable bugs. Creating a separate bug report makes it more manageable to track what has and has not been fixed.

Comment: I will take a closer look, thanks. From my point of view - no need for separate post. Although @MartijnPieters has a point re this being a separate bug caused by bigger change in the code.